# Linux - How to write a glob pattern to that matches all file names with at least one uppercase character in an extension

Tags: linux, bash, macos

How to write regular expression to find all files with at least 1 uppercase character (only) in file extension.

For example:

```
TextFile2.TXT.tXT
TextFile3.TXT.txt
TextFile.Txt
TextFile1.tXt
TextFile.TXT.txT
```

What's wrong with this 'find' command?

```
find . -type f -name "*.*[[:upper:]]*"
```

Output:

```
./TextFile2.TXT.tXT
./TextFile3.TXT.txt        (->this file shouldn't be here) 
./TextFile.Txt
./TextFile1.tXt
./TextFile.TXT.txT
```

Thanks !

Comment: It looks like you mean a shell ("glob") pattern, not a regular expression.  The two are not the same thing, and the former is what `find -name` works with.

Comment: please update the question with the output from your `find` command and an explanation of why it's `'wrong'`; did you receive an error message? did you receive the 'wrong' output?

Comment: Your `find` command seems to work as-is for me on Linux, as indeed I would expect.  But I see that you have tagged both Linux and MacOS, even though the title names only Linux.  The behavior of the command-line tools of these different operating systems is not identical in all respects.

Comment: `*` can match `.`, so `[[:upper:]]` isn't restricted to the *last* extension.

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- OP has provided a `find/glob` code example but mentions `regular expression` in the question; I'm going to assume a `regex` solution is acceptable
- for files that appear to have multiple extensions (eg, `TextFile2.TXT.tXT`) we're only interested in the 'last' extension (ie, what follows the **last** period in the filename)
- files of interest must have at least 1 character following the last period
- we're only interested in filenames with at least 1 capital letter (`A-Z`) following the last period

Sample files:

```
$ ls -1 | sort
TextFile.TXT.txT
TextFile.Txt
TextFile1.tXt
TextFile1.tXt.               # ignore this file
TextFile2.TXT.X
TextFile2.TXT.t              # ignore this file
TextFile2.TXT.tXT
TextFile3.TXT.txt            # ignore this file
```

One idea using `find's` `-regex` option:

```
$ find . -regex '.*TextFile.*[.][^.]*[A-Z]+[^.]*' | sort
./TextFile.TXT.txT
./TextFile.Txt
./TextFile1.tXt
./TextFile2.TXT.X
./TextFile2.TXT.tXT
```

Where:

- `.*` - match anything prior to the string `TextFile`
- `.*[.]` - match everything up to a period followed by ...
- `[^.]*[A-Z]+[^.]*` - zero or more non-periods `+` at least one capital letter `+` zero or more non-periods

**NOTES**:

- the `sort` is not required; `sort` was added to make it easier to compare the 2 lists of filenames
- the above works with (GNU) `find` 4.6.0
- question has been tagged with `macos`; this [MacOS man page for 'find'](https://ss64.com/osx/find.html) appears to show support for the `-regex` option; I don't have access to a MacOS machine to verify if `-regex` works the same as suggested